# How do I complete authentication using the Spotify Web API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I'm trying to generate an access token to access the web player of the SpotifyWebApi and play music in the browser. Even after trying several things, including reading Spotify's authorization documentation for the Authorization Code Flow, I'm still stuck and I can't get an access code. The documentation outlines a 3-step process. Only the first part is working for me, and I'm stuck in the 2nd step. (Spotify Docs: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/)

Here's what I've done:

Step 1:

```
export const authEndpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/";
const clientID = "[redacted]";
const clientSecret = "[redacted]";
const scopes = [
  "user-library-read",
  "user-library-modify",
  "user-read-playback-state",
  "user-read-currently-playing",
  "user-read-recently-played",
  "user-top-read",
  "user-modify-playback-state"
];
export const loginUrl = `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scopes=${scopes.join(
  "%20"
)}&show_dialog=true`;

const ACCESS_CODE = getCodeFromUrl();
```

Step 2:

```
const POST_OBJECT_BODY = {
  grant_type: "authorization_code",
  code: ACCESS_CODE,
  redirect_uri: redirectUri,
  client_id: clientID.toString("base64"),
  client_secret: clientSecret.toString("base64"),
};

fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(POST_OBJECT_BODY),
}).then((response) => {
  console.log("Response: ", response);
});
```

I had to add the "no-cors" part because I was getting CORS errors.

I've tried other authentication methods and they seem to work, but I'm not getting a proper access token. I say this because I'm unable to play the music - it kept saying "Permissions missing" despite me having the proper scopes.

Any help with the above will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a small remark, the redirect uri you are using in step 2 has to be encoded.